# leafony の STM32 Simple BLE Beacon について

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy

leafonyのSTM32 Simple BLE BeaconでBLE通信を試しております。

[STM32 Simple BLE Beacon](https://docs.leafony.com/docs/examples/advanced/3_p/stm32/stm32_simple_ble_beacon/) にあるサンプルプログラム（STM32_Simple_Beacon.ino）をコンパイルしたところ、次のエラーが出力されました。

**Errorログの抜粋:**

```
\Arduino\libraries\STM32duino_RTC\src/STM32RTC.h:42:4: error: #error "This library is not compatible with core version used. Please update the core."
```

コアを更新するようにというエラーですが、どのようにしたらよいのかご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そのエラーメッセージで検索すると、おそらくこのファイル [STM32RTC/src/STM32RTC.h](https://github.com/stm32duino/STM32RTC/blob/main/src/STM32RTC.h) の42行目のことでしょう。その上の41行目の内容からすると`STM32_CORE_VERSION`というマクロのDefine値が`0x02000000`未満なのだと思われます。そうした対象版数の整合性を合わせるように調査・対処してみてください。

Comment: ちなみに検索して見つかるこんなサイト [Documentation | Leafony](https://docs.leafony.com/docs/) によるとハードウェアも3種類くらい？ あるようなので、対応しているものに対する開発環境設定とかは正常に完了して、最初のチュートリアル的な何かは済んでいるのでしょうか？ それとも質問した内容が最初に行ったことなのでしょうか？